# Logging Application Block to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, logging, enterprise-library

Is it possible to use the Logging Application Block of the Enterprise Library (version 5.0) to write log entries to a custom table in SQL Server ?

(edit) changed to 'custom table' because we want to report on specific log-columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to write log entries from your .NET code to a SQL Server database in order to centralize your log store.

If that is the case, then you can definitely do that.  See [Logging to a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664543%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes :)

Same Link as Anders: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569(v=pandp.50).aspx

SQL Server == Database